# Is there a way to store metadata on meetup?

Tags: api, metadata, meetup

I want to use the Meetup.com API to have a group everyone belongs to, but then enable members to receive notifications of certain types of events on their smartphones. For example the group would have 3000 members and have activist meetings, social meetings, and training meetings. Users would be able to specify interests so they would only get notified of the categories they are interested in.

Is there a clean way to do this through the meetup API? If there is metadata like a category that would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at their [event get](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/2/event/#get) api I don't think there is a clean way to do it. Seems storing it as a hidden HTML value is a hacky way to do it. I'll probably end up with another datastore referencing the eventID and store my info there.